# FactoryGirl Not Registered (Only one factory runs into this)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have three models: users, sites, and passports.

users and sites has and belongs to many each other, while passports is the join model with a couple of extra columns.

I've tried both of the following:

1.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :passports do
    association :site, factory: :site
    association :user, factory: :user
    access_token 'mock_token'
  end
end
```

2.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :passports do
    access_token 'mock_token'
  end
end
```

And either way, I'm using it with:

```
let(:site) { FactoryGirl.create :site }
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :user }
let(:site_user) { FactoryGirl.create :site_user, site: site, user: user }
let(:passport) { FactoryGirl.create :passport, user: user, site: site }
```

Please don't ask why there are both site_user and passport..that'll take a while to explain.

Thanks!

Max

Answer (score 0):

So, recapitulating:

```
# Sites
has_many :passports
has_many_and_belongs_to :users, :through => :passport

# User
has_many :passports
has_many_and_belongs to :sites, :through => :passport

# Pasport
belongs_to :site
belongs_to :user
# has a few other things going on as wel
```

I *think* you should be able to do something like

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    # details go here
  end

  factory :site_with_users do
    users { |site| [site.association(:user), site.association(:user)] }
  end
end
```

and then you should be able to do

```
let( :site_with_users ) { FactoryGirl.create :site_with_users }
```

But these are all guesses, hope it will help you on your way.

Comment: No, I think you should define users within a site, the model should know passports is in between them.

Answer (score 0):

OMFG this is dumb...

Switching to the Factory.define :passport do |f| syntax made it work...

Great way to blow away an hour and half of productivity